# Pairwise Point Comparisons in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this dataset I want to compare pairwise observations and using two points (before and after) for each observation (a-d) and a line. The line should be colored according to the relationship between the points (blue for positive, red for negative).  Any ideas on how to do this in ggplot?

```
obs<-c('a','b','c','d') 
before<-c(2,4,6,8)
after<-c(4,2,8,4) 
df<-cbind(before, after)
row.names(df)=obs
as.data.frame(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$col <- factor(df$after - df$before > 0,labels=c("descending","ascending"))

df$obs <- obs

df_l <- gather(df,key,value,-col,-obs)
df_l
ggplot(df_l,aes(x=key,y=value,colour=col,group=obs)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to weight the thickness of the line based on yet another variable?

Comment: take a look at `help("geom_line")`. It accepts a `size` aesthetic to which you could pass this variable